# How to iterate through chars of a string in Postgresql?

Tags: string, postgresql

I have to create a function in PostgreSQL to show the pair characters of a string passed as a parameter.

What I thought was to loop through the chars of the string, like I would do it in C or Java or whatever, but I don't know how to access to a character individually, what would be `str[i]`, for example, being `str` a string, and `i` the position of the char.

What I mean by "pair characters" is characters in pair positions: that is, characters in the string whose position modulo 2 = 0. If the input parameter is "String", the characters showed by the function would be "t" (ie position 2, starting from position 1), and "i" (ie position 4), "g"(position 6).

Comment: Look for the `SUBSTRING` function.

Comment: Please show some input and the expected result output. Also, why? What's the underlying problem you're trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: @Craig Ringer There is no other problem that the one I described. I'm learning PostgreSQL now, and it's a simple exercise ;) An example of the function input and output would be this: "FunctionPairChars('thisIsAString')" Output: hssSrn

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Iteration over an array (best way):

```
FOREACH ch IN ARRAY regexp_split_to_array('hello', '')
LOOP
  ...
END LOOP;
```

---

## Iteration over a table:

```
FOR row_record IN
  SELECT tbl.col
  FROM regexp_split_to_table('hello', '') AS tbl(col)
LOOP
  ...
END LOOP;
```

will iterate over the table `tbl` with column `col`:

```
 col
-----
 h
 e
 l
 l
 o
(5 rows)
```

Access to the value over `row_record.col`.

---

Not sure why you want to "iterate" over strings. Such a task would IMO be better done in a programming language.

Comment: I think that will be great for my function! Thanks! I'll try this afternoon and if it works, I will mark your answer as the answer.

About how I write it in PostgreSQL, as I said, it's because it's a simple exercise from a book, and that is the specification.

Comment: I have a really similar question. I'm trying to loop through a string of characters, but I'm struggling to understand this...

FOREACH ch IN ARRAY regexp_split_to_array('hello', '')
LOOP
  ...
END LOOP;

It'd be super helpful if you could provide an example.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem specification is really, really unclear. So it's hard to guess what you really want.

Say you want *pairs of characters*, such that the input string `abcd` returns `ab,bc,cd`. That's as good a guess as any from the vague description provided.

If that's what you want, here's one possible solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION charpairs(text) RETURNS SETOF text AS $$
SELECT substring($1 from x for 2) FROM generate_series(1, length($1)-1) x;
$$
LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;
```

usage:

```
regress=> SELECT * FROM charpairs('abcd');
 charpairs 
-----------
 ab
 bc
 cd
(3 rows)
```

Not what you wanted? **Define the problem properly**. Usually half the challenge in programming is properly defining a problem. Once you do that well, the code often almost writes its self. Start with the inputs and desired outputs. Work from the ends into the middle.

---

After update in comments:

You want chars with `position % 2 == 1`. So one approach is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION everysecond(text) RETURNS SETOF text AS $$
SELECT substring($1 from x for 1) FROM generate_series(2, length($1), 2) x;
$$
LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;
```

possibly with a `string_agg` in there if you want a string not a set as a result.

Comment: My bad, sometimes it's hard to express myself in English where it is not my native language. Sorry about that.

What I meant with "pair characters" was "characters in pair positions", that is, characters in the string whose position MOD 2 = 0. As I said, if the input parameter is "String", the characters showed by the function would be "t"(position 2, starting from position 1), "i"(position 4), "g"(position 6).

Thanks anyway for the help.